# Chartboost ads not working in libgdx project

Tags: java, android, libgdx, chartboost

Hi I'm integrating Chartboost in my game but the ads aren't showing in live and testing mode. I followed this tutorial in exact manner and there is no error in my code https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX

In https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX/blob/master/android/src/com/its/adservice/AndroidLauncher.java line 34 I changed to ad=new ChartBoostHelper(this); I removed the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods and also I made other changes. I called the show ads method in the right place but it does not show.

I registered Chartboost and added my appId and signature accordingly and also set the setting to landscape and interstitial ads. I have modified the AndroidManifest file as in the tutorial and added the jar file in /android/libs folder. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

This is my android/AndroidLauncher.java and the ChartBoostHelper and the Ad class is the same as in the github link.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver {
    private Ad ad;
    public RelativeLayout layout;
    View gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;
        config.useImmersiveMode = true;

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        View gameView=initializeForView(new MyGame(this), config);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        gameView.setLayoutParams(gameViewParams);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        ad=new ChartBoostHelper(this);
        ad.embedView(layout);

        setContentView(layout);

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ad.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        ad.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ad.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ad.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ad.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void showOrLoadInterstitial() {
        ad.showOrLoadInterstitial();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean showVideoAd(boolean isRewarded) {

        return ad.showVideoAd(isRewarded);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This is the core/ActionResolver.java

```
public interface ActionResolver {

    void showOrLoadInterstitial();
    boolean showVideoAd(boolean isRewarded);
}
```

This is the part where I call showOrLoadInterstitial(); in the render method inside of core/GameScreen.java

```
        if((touchPos.x >= camera.position.x-(replaybutton.getWidth()/2 + 50) && touchPos.x <= (camera.position.x - (replaybutton.getWidth()/2 + 50))+replaybutton.getWidth()) && (touchPos.y>=55 && touchPos.y<=55+replaybutton.getHeight())){
           if(SplashScreen.adcount >= 4 && prefs.getBoolean("ADBLOCK") == false){
                game.actionResolver.showOrLoadInterstitial();
                SplashScreen.adcount = 0;
            }
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game,this.asset));
            dispose();
        }
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.robot1gamesfree.game"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.robot1gamesfree.game.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You should share your code. Do you display ads in UI thread? You might be using try and catch and trying to show libgdx thread and ads don't display and app doesn't crash or you might not be getting ads from server with error code or other millions of reasons can be the cause. You should post your code for how you set and display ads.

Comment: @Thracian done! Could you please help? :)

Comment: You might get an error from server when loading ads. I don't use Chartboost but it looks like AdMob. add listener to your ads and there must be a callback method like onAdLoadFailed(), see if you are getting any error, you may also listen the method when on success like onAdLoaded().

Comment: @Thracian I actually don't know how to do that. Can you be a little more detailed, like show an example code?

Comment: @Thracian I actually found the mistake! It is in my android manifest file, I put the chartboost activity tag in the application activity tag, I should be putting it outside. Thanks for your suggestion though :)